# text from text area dont go to php with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code, and also I am new to AJAX. What I want to do is that after I click the Encrypt button, the text area needs to be cleared while the text that I wrote in the textarea to go to my PHP script. With this code, the text area is cleared, but the text that I write in the textarea doesnt get in my php script so that it can get encrypted. my code is as follows:

```
<script> 
    function clearText(){
        $("#forma").submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "php/rsa.php", 
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "text",
                data: $("#rsa").val()
            });
            $("#rsa").val('');
        });
    }     
</script>
```

[HTML PART](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wobRW.png)

RSA.php

```
<?php $data = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '"<br>"',$_POST['teksti']); if($_POST['RSA'] == 'Encrypt'){
$result = shell_exec("C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe ../python/rsaCipher.py $data" );
echo $result;
header('Content-type: text');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="encrypted.txt"');
}
```

Comment: Why are you sending text, send it as JSON or a serialized value and then on the other side break that down into a string...

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Show us the code for rsa.php and the form with the textarea.

Comment: this is the rsa.php

<?php
$data = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '"<br>"',$_POST['teksti']);

if($_POST['RSA'] == 'Encrypt'){
 $result = shell_exec("C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe ../python/rsaCipher.py $data" );
 echo $result;
 header('Content-type: text');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="encrypted.txt"');
 }
I uploaded a pic for my form code in my post.

Comment: No update the original post, the code in the comment is not formatted and thus not helpful

Comment: hahaha ok man sorry I am new to this one this is my first post

Comment: So the only problem is that your PHP isn't receiving the value of #rsa? It seems like everything is fine. Did you do a var dump to see if you got the value? When I do AJAX I usually use $_REQUEST['RSA'] instead of POST.

Comment: yessss thats the whole point garek007!! it is not going in rsa.php the value of #rsa. should I try the request ha?

Comment: ITS WORKING GAREK!! thanks for the ideas you guys. I found the solution like all I had to do is change as garek suggested to $_REQUEST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using $_REQUEST instead of $_POST in your php file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution you guys!!

I used the $_REQUEST as garek suggested.

THANKS garek!!

Comment: Hey how bout let me post the answer then and you mark it right? :)